# Ajax Web service on Firefox page unload

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, web-services, asp.net-ajax

```
$addHandler(window,'unload',function() {
  wsPageMetrics.LogCsPageMetricEvent('test', 12); 
});
```

`wsPageMetrics` is a web service which has log method in it.

The above piece of code works fine for IE and Chrome but it doesn't work for Firefox. I have also tried `beforeunload` for Firefox but it still won't call the web service. If I put in an alert after the web service call, then it would execute the service, which to me is obvious that it gets enough time to finish the web service call.

In a live site obviously I don't want an alert.. Is there a work around?

Comment: Have you tried put the call into `setTimeout`?

Comment: hmm i havent , let me try that

Comment: @YuriyGalanter are you saying to put a setTimeout after the service call or to call the service within the settimeout . If i call the service within the setTimeout it doesnot work

Comment: Yes I was thinking of placing actual webservice call into setTimeout to take it out of context. It helped me before in similar scenarios

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Yeah i tried that it didnt work cause if you think about it settimeout is going  to call that webservice after certain seconds but at the same time it will also unload the page resulting in the same behaviour. Just can't believe why FF needs to make things complex cause it works fine for IE and chrome

Comment: Good point. Then you may have to add a JS code that would wait for webserice call to return and only then allow onunload/onbeforeunload to continue

Comment: @YuriyGalanter i checked some forums about that but i think they've got the sample problems cause the page wont wait for something to come back

Comment: In that case instead of making WebService call via `Class.Method` notation you will need to make a direct *synchronous* AJAX call to that server-side code. This way, because call is synchronous - page will wait.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Good point but when you say direct synchronous AJAX . This is a contradictory statement. As Ajax cant be synchronous. If you intend to say call a web method directly , can you highlight sample implementation of calling webmethod from javascript?

Comment: I know what AJAX acronym stands for, but nevertheless the call can be synchronous. I am not at my PC at the moment, please take a look at XMLHttpRequest and its methods and if you still having problems I will post an example later on.